# Why does my ARRAYFORMULA return this error?

Tags: google-sheets

Edit: I've completely rewritten by question because it turned out a syntax mistake was giving me the error my question was originally about, but it wasn't the direct reason my formula wasn't working.  Here is the correct question to my problem, and the solution I have posted as an answer.

I'm having trouble with converting a current formula to ARRAYFORMULA.

The original formula starts with this and is copied and pasted down to F134 where the table ends:

```
=IF(C88="","", 
IF(OR(vlookup($B88,'Detailed Analysis'!$A$7:$AN,31, false)="MISSING",(vlookup($B88,'Detailed Analysis'!$A$7:$AN,32, false)="MISSING")),"MISSING", 
C88*vlookup($B88,'Detailed Analysis'!$A$7:$AN,31, false)
+C88*vlookup($B88,'Detailed Analysis'!$A$7:$AN,32, false)))
```

Comment: Impossible to tell without having a look at your data. Taking the error at face value, it tells you everything you need to know: some of the vlookups are failing to find the values in the ranges where you are searching.

Comment: Well the thing is that they don't fail when they're not in an ARRAYFORMULA.  So I don't understand what the error is trying to tell me.

Comment: I've updated my question with a link to a copy of my full spreadsheet so that you can see my data directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Best Answer chosen on [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/U541KrM_Amg) post and the only answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43710792/arrayformula-and-and-formula-in-google-sheets) post, OR cannot be used inside an ARRAYFORMULA because it:

> [OR]s the whole array together in the top left cell...
>   regardless of number of dimensions."

Therefore, it seems that the solution I have currently of nesting an IF inside an IF is the most reasonable workaround to using OR inside an ARRAYFORMULA.

The working formula, using nested IF statements, becomes this:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(C88:C134="","", 
IF(vlookup($B88:$B134,'Detailed Analysis'!$A$7:$AN,31, false)="MISSING","MISSING", 
IF(vlookup($B88:$B134,'Detailed Analysis'!$A$7:$AN,32, false)="MISSING","MISSING", 
C88:C134*vlookup($B88:$B134,'Detailed Analysis'!$A$7:$AN,31, false)
+C88:C134*vlookup($B88:$B134,'Detailed Analysis'!$A$7:$AN,32, false)))))
```